# Getting data once and use it in all activities

Tags: android, singleton

I have a question about getting data from server.
I get general data in mainActivity of my app and I want to use it across all activities. I was thinking about using database to get my data once, save it in database and get it where I want from database. But now I'm thinking about using a Singleton class that I can use it to save data once amd get that data in every activity. Is it possible and is it a good idea?

Update :

Data Type is list of objects, So SharedPrefrences is not a good choice
and I want to save them temporally until application is running.

Comment: `Singleton` is good if you want to use temporary save data, otherwise use `sharedprefrences` or `SQLite`, you can `Singleton` with `sharedprefrences`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save the data in any of the following sources

1. Shared Preferences
2. SqlLite Database
3. Android Room or any other ORM
4. Files (specially for images)

Based on your data type, you can decide one among these

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen the [Android Event Bus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus)? It makes communications between activities fun! Your main activity "posts" the data object once it is available. Other activities "subscribe" to receive the posted data.